# list <ul> and <li> php mysql with id

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-lists

here I want to create a list of `<ul>` and `<li>` which is not limited when input in the database, here I do not find any problem in creating `<li>` and `<ul>` in one or two lists and three lists using `<ul>` and `< li>`, but here I want to create an infinite list of `<li>` and `<ul>`, can someone help me?

my code :

```
<?php
    $get_main = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_akun WHERE parent_akun = '0'");

    foreach($get_main AS $main){
        $main_kode  = preg_replace('/0+/','',$main['kode_akun']);
?>
<div class="ulli-none">
    <ul>
        <li><?= $main_kode ?> - <?= $main['nama_akun'] ?>
            <ul>
                <?php 
                    $get_parent = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_akun WHERE parent_akun = {$main['kode_akun']}");

                    foreach($get_parent AS $parent){
                ?>
                <li><?= $main_kode ?>-<?= $parent['kode_akun'] ?> <?= $parent['nama_akun'] ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php 
                            $get_subs = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_akun WHERE parent_akun = {$parent['kode_akun']}");

                            foreach($get_subs AS $subs){
                        ?>
                        <li><?= $main_kode ?>-<?= $subs['kode_akun'] ?> <?= $subs['nama_akun'] ?></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: when you fetch the values from DB, you should group it in the array accordingly, then finally just loop it along the markup

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a recursive function for this.

```php
<?php
$get_main = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_akun WHERE parent_akun = '0'");
?>
<div class="ulli-none">
    <?php
    recursiveList($get_main, $db);
    ?>
</div>
<?php

function recursiveList($items, $db, $mainPrefix = ''){

    if (empty($items)){
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach($items AS $item){

            if (!$mainPrefix) {
                $prefix = $mainPrefix = preg_replace('/0+/','', $item['kode_akun']);
            } else {
                $prefix = $mainPrefix . ' - ' . $item['kode_akun'];
            }

            ?>
            <li>
                <span><?= $prefix ?> - <?= $item['nama_akun'] ?></span>
                <?php
                $subs = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_akun WHERE parent_akun = {$item['kode_akun']}");

                recursiveList($subs, $db, $mainPrefix);

                ?>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Keep in mind that you're querying the subs for every record. This will become time consuming when there're a lot of records. To further optimize this you might want to fetch all records and collect them within an array; E.g.

```php
$get_main = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_akun");

$all = [];
foreach ($get_main as $item) {
    if (empty($all[$item['parent_akun']])) {
        $all[$item['parent_akun']] = [];
    }
    $all[$item['parent_akun']][$item['kode_akun']] = $item;
}

?>
<div class="ulli-none">
    <?php
    recursiveList($all);
    ?>
</div>
<?php

function recursiveList($all, $parentId = 0, $mainPrefix = ''){

    if (empty($all[$parentId])){
        return;
    }
    
    $items = $all[$parentId];
    
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach($items AS $item){

            if (!$mainPrefix) {
                $prefix = $mainPrefix = preg_replace('/0+/','', $item['kode_akun']);
            } else {
                $prefix = $mainPrefix . ' - ' . $item['kode_akun'];
            }

            ?>
            <li>
                <span><?= $prefix ?> - <?= $item['nama_akun'] ?></span>
                <?php
                    recursiveList($all, $item['kode_anun'], $mainPrefix );
                ?>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}

?>
```